# Only first character of label recognised. Remainder displayed as text

Tags: align, labels

In a particular document, `align` labels are only recognised as being the first character of the specified label, with the remainder being printed as text.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides the align environment
\usepackage{autonum} % Only number referenced equations
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false,doi=false,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs} % nicer tables, provides toprule midrule etc
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % provides the cref command
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for stargazer R tables
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allow non-ascii characters in .bib file
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint} % For rounding numbers in tabulars. Provides num command
\usepackage{rotating} % provides sideways table environment
\usepackage[group-separator={,},
    group-minimum-digits = 4]  % default is 5
    {siunitx} % Adds the S column type. Provides num command
\usepackage{subfig} % For side-by-side tables

\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
Here's an equation:

\begin{align}\label{eqn:first}
    f^{(1)}_{ij} = \frac{f^{(0)}_{ij} O_i}{\sum\limits_k f_{ik}}
\end{align}

In \cref{eqn:first} lots of stuff happens. Here's another:
\begin{align}\label{eqn:second}
    f^{(2)}_{ij}
    = \frac{f^{(1)}_{ij} D_j}{\sum\limits_k f^{(1)}_{kj}}
    = \frac{O_i D_j}{\sum\limits_k O_k}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:
[image: Align label misinterpreted]

The label is being read as being the character `e` only, as shown by this excerpt from the `.aux` file:

```
\newlabel{e}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{e@cref}{{[equation][1][]1}{1}}
```

It must have something to do with the preamble (which is why I've included it in the MWE) but what?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that doesn't seem to be the problem. Moving the label to after the equation doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and having `cleveref` loaded last makes no difference either.

Comment: It is package `autonum` that kicks the label in the butt.

Comment: A small side note: I don't think that it's a good idea to only number equations which are referenced. Perhaps another one citing your document would rather refer to another equation which is numbered then. This could be confusing

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's odd, but some journals have this as a submission requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `autonum` must be included even after `cleveref` and in my impression, the document must be compiled thrice to get all the references working.

The manual clearly says

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides the align environment
%
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=false,doi=false,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs} % nicer tables, provides toprule midrule etc
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for stargazer R tables
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allow non-ascii characters in .bib file
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint} % For rounding numbers in tabulars. Provides num command
\usepackage{rotating} % provides sideways table environment
\usepackage[group-separator={,},
    group-minimum-digits = 4]  % default is 5
    {siunitx} % Adds the S column type. Provides num command
\usepackage{subfig} % For side-by-side tables

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % provides the cref command
\usepackage{autonum} % Only number referenced equations
\begin{document}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
Here's an equation:

\begin{align}  
    f^{(1)}_{ij} &= \frac{f^{(0)}_{ij} O_i}{\sum\limits_k f_{ik}} \label{eqn:first}
\end{align}

In \cref{eqn:first} lots of stuff happens. Here's another:
\begin{align}
    f^{(2)}_{ij}
    &= \frac{f^{(1)}_{ij} D_j}{\sum\limits_k f^{(1)}_{kj}} \label{eqn:second} \\
    &= \frac{O_i D_j}{\sum\limits_k O_k}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, and can be summarised as: load `autonum` after `cleveref` (as the post now states. Thanks @ChristianHupfer)

Comment: @LondonRob: As I have written at the top of the post ;-)